# CSS Slider resolution problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a slider on my webpage that I've made. It looks good in 720p resolution. Everything is centered as it should be, etc.. But when I change my resolution to 1080p, the slider gets off-center for some reason. I've tried everything I know to try in the CSS and alas, I am stumped. Below is the CSS, and I'll provide the link to the webpage farther down.

```
#slider {
position: static;
margin-left: 22%;
width: 720px;
height: 400px;
overflow: hidden;
```

}

www.test.brandonmiller3d.com

Note: if the link adds "/test/" to the end of the url, just delete it and press enter. Something's up in my .htaccess file as well lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `margin: 0 auto` on the `#slider`:

```
#slider {
    width: 720px;
    height: 400px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Haha, you're a genius xP. Thanks bud! I would vote you up, but don't have the rep to.

Comment: @BrandonMiller You could mark his answer as correct instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have a left margin of 22% on your slider.

change this

```
#slider {
  position: static;
  margin-left: 22%;
  width: 720px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

to this

```
#slider {
  position: static;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 720px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: why address margin-* separately instead of margin: ?

Comment: it's just more readable *(isn't it?)* and means the same as `margin: 0 auto`. You can use either of them.

Comment: If you check out your Chrome Timeline and record the creation of the following pages then you'll see a consistent ~15ms +- 10ms difference between <div style="margin:50px;"></div> & <div style="margin-left:50px;margin-right:50px;margin-top:50px;margin-bottom:50px;"></div>. Test it for yourself. http://jsfiddle.net/8y087r4h/    http://jsfiddle.net/x9wygbrd/